# openssl convert id_rsa.pub to DER output

Tags: command-line, openssl, ssh-keys

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the openssl tool to convert rsa public keys.

This works fine for a private key

```
$ openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout -outform DER > out
writing RSA key
```

If I only have a public key, I thought I'd be able to do the same and just add "-pubin".  But I get a cryptic error complaining it was expecting a public key ... but that is what I gave it.

```
$ openssl rsa -pubin -in id_rsa.pub -pubout -outform DER > out
unable to load Public Key
140028314654360:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: PUBLIC KEY
```

In case I was supposed to use pkey instead I tried that and I still get that error, but without the second line

```
$ openssl pkey -pubin -in id_rsa.pub -pubout -outform DER > out
unable to load Public Key
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSL does not understand OpenSSH-format public keys. (It is mostly just a coincidence that they both use the same private key format, too – in fact, recent OpenSSH started using a different, incompatible one.)

With recent OpenSSH, you can use `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -e -m PEM` to get a PKCS#1 file.

Similarly, `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -e -m PKCS8` will give you the key in PKCS#8 format.

You can also extract OpenSSL-format public key from the private file using `-in id_rsa -pubout`.

Comment: I need to find a solution that only uses the public key. (Sadly, I currently resorted to just converting to DER format in a small python script. I'd still like to understand how to use the command line tools correctly though.) `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa.pub -e -m PEM > tmp.pem` completes fine. Then `openssl rsa -pubin -in tmp.pem -pubout -outform DER > out` still gives me the error about having trouble loading a public key.

Comment: Huh, it worked with PKCS8 though.